# Does the kernel data structure klist provide threadsafe access?

Tags: linux-kernel

Does the linked list wrapper described in klist.h provide threadsafe access to its nodes for both reading and writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "reading and writing" you actually mean "interating and adding/removing" (we're talking about lists, right?).

In this sense they are thread-safe: you do not have to perform manual locking on them because the functions defined in `lib/klist.c` use the internal spinlock of the klist structure.

Do **not** use these functions if interrupt or bottom half context, because the locking done inside them is ***not*** `spin_lock_irqsave()` or `spin_lock_bh()`.